# Performance improvoment in a $addfields query mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm doing a performance improvement in a MongoDB query, the query search for a value in a String field and a numeric field.

The actual query uses $addField to search in numeric fields like a text field, with this we can use regex to do something like this:

The user types '123'

Search for not only the exact match, but if the data contains '123' like these examples:

```
{
 name: 123 Example
 usedId: 9595
}
{
 name: Example
 usedId: 1123
}
```

Both registers will be returned because one of them has '123' on name fields and the other one contains '123' in userId.

But, $addFields doesn't use indexes, and this impacts the query's performance.

There is a way to use $addFields with indexes, or to make regex with numbers, or something like that to improve performance?

My solution until now is this query that uses indexes is:

```
[
  {
  $match:
      {
        $or: [
                    {
            name:
                    {
                      $regex: "123", $options: "i"
                    }
            },
          {
              userId :
            {
                // idk what command I should use here
            }
          }
            ]
      }
  }
]
```

The actual aggregation pipeline is:

```
   [
    { 
        $addFields: 
        { 
            userId: 
            {
                $toString: '$userId'
            }   
        } 
    },
    { 
        $match: 
            { 
                $or: 
                    [ 
                        {
                            name: 
                                {
                                    $regex: '?0', 
                                    $options:'i'
                                }
                        }, 
                        {
                            userId: {
                                    $regex: '?0'
                                }
                        }, 
                    ] 
            } 
    },
    { 
        $group: 
            { 
                _id: 
                    { 
                        userId: "$userId", 
                        name: "$name", 
                    } 
            } 
    },
    { 
        $project: 
            { 
            _id: 0, userId: "$_id.userId", 
            name: "$_id.name" 
            } 
    },
    { 
        $sort : { 
            name : 1 
            } 
    },
    { 
        $facet: { 
            metadata: [ 
                { 
                    $count: "total" 
                } 
            ], 
            data: [ 
                { 
                    $skip: '?1' 
                }, 
                { 
                    $limit: '?2' 
                } 
            ] 
        } 
    }
   ]
```

Comment: My first advice would be, use and store numeric values as number not as string. How does your current `$addFields` look like? Regular expressions are always slow.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I add the current $addFields

Comment: Why do you like to query numeric value by a string? Use simple `{userId: parseInt('123')}`, it will also use an index.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit i tried to {userId: parseInt('123')}, but it didn't worked, it's show 'Stage value is invalid'

Comment: `parseInt()` is JavaScript, I guess there is a similar function in Java.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for you to to effectively use an index for this query.

Perhaps if the "substring" you're looking for is not random we could in theory think of a way that is heuristically better than a collection scan but that sounds unlikely.

Your 2 options are:

1. keep using your query with an `$addFields` to cast the number.
2. Just save the `userId` as string to begin with (or atleast create a new field like `userIdStr` and index that field for this query).